# JabRef exportfilter for Wikipedia citation

Tags: parsing, wikipedia, bibtex

I want to cite inside Wikipedia sources which are stored in my JabRef Database. According to the [jabref-documentation](https://docs.jabref.org/import-export/export/customexports)  I need a custom exportfilter which is a file like 
`wikipediacitation.layout`. This layout file converts a JabRef database into the wikipedia-syntax for pasting it at the end of an article. The description of the output format is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Cite_journal).  My problem is, that the creation of a Jabref-layout-file seems to be complicated. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer by myself.

The following files have to be created:

```
wikicite.layout:
<ref name=\bibtexkey>{{cite journal
 | author = \author
 | title = \title
 | year = \year
 | journal = \journal
 | volume = \volume
 | pages = \pages
 | url = \url 
}}</ref>

wikicite.begin.layout:
==References==
<references>

wikicite.end.layout
</references>
```

Then, a new export filter has to be added into Jabref (options -> manage custom exports -> add new). But even I've found myself the answer, thanks to Stackoverflow for listening to my problem.

Comment: Please file a pull request to https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/ for integrating the feature directly in JabRef. The target directory should be created in https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/tree/master/src/main/resources/resource/layout.